# Having problems configuring GPIO pins on rpi with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to control the fan speed of a fan connected to the rpi via 5V power, 3.3V control and GND.

This is my simple code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(1,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.PWM(1, 50)
```

I am getting a "The channel sent is invalid on a Raspberry Pi". Everything is up to date and i can't seem to find a solution online.

Comment: It does not support PWM on that GPIO port. Try pin12 GPIO18!

Comment: oh, i see. Thank you, but i have nothing that i can connect to that port, my 3.3v control is connected to pin1, i tried to output 0 and 1 to atleast turn the fan on and off, but i'm still getting the same error. Is it even possible to control the state of the voltage pins like the pin number 1, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.